# Unity doesn't load properly, no launcher, no window options

Tags: boot, icons

When I booted up Ubuntu 14.10 today and logged in, there was no launcher or menu at the top; just desktop icons. I can only access the hard terminal and there are no buttons to maximize, close or minimize windows.

Comment: run the command `gnome-session-quit` logout then login again. Does the problem still?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1166765). A fix is done by:

Firstly, install dconf-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

reset Compiz and Unity by using the following command:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then reset unity:

```
setsid unity
```

Comment: I get error messages when trying to download dconf-tools. I tried sudo apt-get update, but with no luck. When I try the setsid unity command, it gets stuck at "compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: core" :-(